# AccessDeniedException: Not Authorized to perform sagemaker:ListModelPackageGroups

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have the following permission policy on an IAM Role

```
statement {
   effect = "Allow"
   actions = [
      "sagemaker:CreateModelPackageGroup",
      "sagemaker:ListModelPackageGroups",
]
resources = [
    "arn:aws:sagemaker:my_account_region:my_account_id:model-package-group/*",
]
```

to be able to create a `ModelPackageGroup` using boto3

```
import boto3
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
mpg_name = 'my_model_package_name'
matching_mpg = sagemaker_client.list_model_package_groups(NameContains=mpg_name)[
    "ModelPackageGroupSummaryList"
]

if matching_mpg:
    logger.info(f"Using existing Model Package Group: {mpg_name}")
else:
    mpg_input_dict = {
        "ModelPackageGroupName": mpg_name,
        "ModelPackageGroupDescription": mpg_description,
    }
    mpg_response = sagemaker_client.create_model_package_group(**mpg_input_dict)
```

but I got the following error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListModelPackageGroups operation: User: arn:aws:sts::my_account_id:assumed-role/my_role_name/botocore-session-some_session_id is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:ListModelPackageGroups because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:ListModelPackageGroups action
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I've found out that the SageMaker Action `ListModelPackageGroups` requires an `All Resources` permission

> The actions in your policy do not support resource-level permissions and require you to choose All resources

In fact, the [Actions defined by Amazon SageMaker Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsagemaker.html) mentions that **some SageMaker actions support resource level permission and others must specify all resources**

> The Resource types column indicates whether each action supports resource-level permissions. If there is no value for this column, you must specify all resources ("*") in the Resource element of your policy statement. If the column includes a resource type, then you can specify an ARN of that type in a statement with that action.

So, changing to the following policy worked out

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:ListModelPackageGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:CreateModelPackageGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sagemaker:my_account_region:my_account_id:model-package-group/*"
        }
    ]
}
```